# Locally install NPM package, unable to find eslint dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint

I'm developing a Vuejs application which has a dependency on an npm package which I've developed. When I'm working on the package I'd like to include it in the vue application, so I can easily see the changes using hot reloading.

I've installed the package locally using `npm i <path to package>` but when I try to run the vue application I get this error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
Error: Failed to load plugin 'import' declared in '../../library/.eslintrc.json » eslint-config-standard': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-import'
```

Its failing to find the eslint plugin from the node_modules in the dependent package, I've tried installing the plugin globally, but that did not help.

Using `npm pack` on the dependent package, and installing it using `npm i <path to tar>` works, but for each alteration of the dependent package I need to re-pack it, re-install it, and re-start the vue application to view the changes, which is not ideal.

Is there any way to tell npm/eslint to look in the node_modules for the dependent package for the plugin, or is there a better work flow I could use?